# DB2 Table change not showing in results for DropDownList on ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, db2

I have an asp:DropDownList being populated from an asp:SqlDataSource that is pointing to an underlying AS400/DB2 table.  Back in March I updated the column size on the field that is used for the value in the dropdownlist from 1 character to 2 characters.  Until now I didn't have an issue because there was instances of 2 character data coming through, but now it is.  My issue is that locally my page works fine, it's picking up both characters for the value in the dropdownlist.  However, on the production site the values are truncated so the list item that should be a value of "10" is showing up as "1" so when the user selects it it's like he selected "1".

I'm not as familiar with the ASP.NET IIS underlying caching.  I've tried to recycle the application pool, and clear the cache on the server and restart the server thinking that the table definition is stored there but I cannot figure out for the life of me where that should be updated.

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to figure out more what's going, first - why do you think this is caching related?  And if so, it's unlikely that the underlying db is the problem, exactly.  DB2 would also throw if you tried to stick a 2-character string in a 1-character field.  Since the table seems to have the different values, I'd actually expect something in regular application code is truncating the field before display.

Comment: Well the code on my dev page is the same as the code that is live (I ended up attempting to copy everything over from dev including DLL's, etc.), both pages pull from the live table.  Locally I can see two character data being returned.  And with the same underlying query the live page is truncating that same field and only showing one character.I'm only guessing that it's a caching issue because I can't figure out why the same query on the same table pulls back different data.  I don't do a lot of work with ASP or IIS so I'm hoping this is just something I'm overlooking.

Comment: I have also tried to create a new SQLdatasource and dropdown list with different names but pulling the same information from the underlying table and on the locahost server it works fine, but live it's still only pulling back one character.

Comment: ...I shudder at what you've just implied about your deployment process.  Your live table actually contains 2-character data, and returns the extra values to the web page, right (even if truncated)?  You're getting two `1`s, right?  That means the cache (if you're even using it - you haven't provided any details) has been updated.  Depending on implementation, the caching may not even care about string length in the first place.  And local (or at least dev) should have had the same setup, including caching, anyways.  The first thing I'd check is output field lengths.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not using any caching, that was just my best guess on why the live site would be any different than the dev. I am seeing two 1s in the live site. I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the difference between the two. It's acting like something is holding on the old table definition.